# How to transform/distort screen?

Tags: xorg, xrandr, ffmpeg, wayland, randr

I have a projector, which doesn't come with horizontal keystone correction builtin, only vertical correction.
I've seen that it is possible to do it with xrandr, using the --transform parameter, but needs matrix coordinates and I'm lost. There's a GUI, ARandR, but doesn't support transformations.

I've also checked MapMap project, but seems a v4l2 virtual video device stream fed by ffmpeg's x11grab isn't well recognized to use it as source.

Do you know any other alternative to transform the screen (free style, like a trapezoid)?

Is there something similar on Wayland display server?

Answer (score 4):

This is a [graphical helper](https://github.com/qurn/xrandr-keystone-helper) to find the **xrandr --tranform parameters**.

[image]